# Azure Devops agent on linux , already add agent but could not execute sh

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, ubuntu-22.04, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I just add a linux agent for Azure devops Pipeline to execute job.
try a simple script, but at the beginning it stop.

information below:

**agent install path and version：**

- Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2
- `vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.5.tar.gz`
- [agent filepath img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js1S2.png)
- work and agent are in the same folder

**JOB LOG**

- Initial JOB
  [Initial JOB pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmjKM.png)
- check out code and Error msg
  [error msg pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElSvk.png)

I find out：
if I execute the run.sh ,connecting the server will take along time, although in the end i add agent succeed, that confuse me.

After checking the profile,i didnot setting the proxy.
curl the azure server is find, i can reach the response.

I don't understand whats going on And i still couldn't execute the script......

Comment: It seems is a networking issue between your Linux agent machine and your Azure DevOps Server 2020 machine. There looks like a delay between the machines. You can try to ping the Azure DevOps Server 2020 machine from the agent machine to see if there also is delay. If so, the problem should be with the networking issue.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT i traceroute  only takes 0.359 ms and curl all fine.  delay didn't happen.....

Comment: Can you try to set up a self-hosted agent on the machine of your Azure DevOps Server 2020 to see whether the same issue occurs?

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT  this issue is happen on self-hosted agent.

Comment: I mean setting up the self-hosted agent on the same machine with your Azure DevOps Server 2020, not another machine.